# Can't create Firestore through Terraform (403 The caller does not have permission)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

My service account has the following roles:

- App Engine Admin
- App Engine Creator
- Cloud Datastore Owner
- Editor
- Owner

I am trying to create the database through Terraform with the following configuration:

```
resource "google_app_engine_application" "app" {
  project     = var.project_id #"my-project-id-xxxxx"
  location_id = var.region # "us-central1"
  database_type = "CLOUD_FIRESTORE"
}
```

Unfortunately it throws an error:

```
│ Error: Error creating App Engine application: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden
│
│   with google_app_engine_application.app,
│   on main.tf line 28, in resource "google_app_engine_application" "app":
│   28: resource "google_app_engine_application" "app" {
```

I am using my personal GCP account, it's not managed by any organization.
I have no problem with other resources in Terraform (like cloud functions, gateway api and etc)
What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating a Cloud Firestore DB, you must own the project. You need to have an **App Engine Owner Role** on the project to make it work.

If you are using the primitive roles refer to official GCP documentation on [Roles that Grant Access to App Engine(Primitive Roles)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/roles#basic_roles) :

> **`Owner:Role`**
>
> **Google Cloud console permissions:** Required to create App Engine applications. All viewer and editor privileges, plus the ability to
> view deployed source code, invite users, change user roles, and delete
> an application. Has admin privileges to all project resources.
>
> **Tools permissions:** Required to create App Engine applications. Can also deploy application code and update all configurations.